# Why will python function max() return different outputs if float('NaN') value is permuted in a dictionary but key-max_value remains the same?

Tags: python, dictionary, max, nan, key-value

Let's pretend I have the following simple dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'a':3, 'b':4, 'c':float('NaN')}
```

If I use function max() to return the key with maximum value...

```
key_maxvalue = max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)
print(key_maxvalue)
```

...python outputs this:

```
b
```

However, when I permute the values of keys 'a' and 'c'...

```
dictionary = {'a':float('NaN'), 'b':4, 'c':3}
key_maxvalue = max(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)
print(key_maxvalue)
```

...I get this unexpected result:

```
a
```

I expected python would output 'b', as that key still has the maximum value in the dictionary. Why has a change in the values order altered the function max() output? Furthermore, how could I prevent this (unexpected) event from happening?

Comment: Also see <https://lwn.net/Articles/869231/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, "don't use NaN".  The point of an NaN is that it is not a number, and cannot be relied on to act like a number in any rational way.  What you're seeing is that comparisons with NaN are not commutative.

Notice this:

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = float('NaN')
>>> 1 < x
False
>>> x < 1
False
>>>
```

Every comparison with a NaN is false.  That makes sorting them indeterminate.

Comment: See also discussion here https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80276

Comment: Can you demonstrate that they're not transitive? Transitive means that xRy and yRz implies xRz. What x,y,z,R involving NaN violate that?

Comment: You're correct, I should have said "commutative".

Comment: I guess you can see a relation as an operation, but even then, comparisons with "normal" numbers are already not commutative. For example, `1 < 2` doesn't equal `2 < 1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote your own function, it might look like this:

```
def max(nums):
    largest = nums[0]

    for item in nums:
        if item > largest:
            largest = item

    return largest
```

The problem is this comparison `item > largest`. Look what happens when you compare a number with `np.nan`.

Input: `np.nan > 4`

Output: `False`

Input: `4 > np.nan`

Output: `False`

Any comparison with a `NaN` will be False. If `max` functions like our written function, then it happens what happens in both of your cases. It's not larger than 4, so `b` is still the max. However, when it defaults to `a` in the second case, no other number is larger than `NaN`, so `a` remains the max.